# How to add a page break before header automatically in pandoc

Tags: lua, markdown, docx, pandoc

I need to convert a markdown document into a Word document.
I need it so that before each header there is a page break.

For example, here, a page break would be inserted before `# Heading 1` and before `# Heading 2`. I wouldn't mind if it skipped the very first one if there is no content before it in the document.

```
# Heading 1

Hello

# Heading 2

World
```

I have found [this Lua filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/pagebreak/pagebreak.lua), but, as far as I understand, it's just for Latex and it's not automatic.

I have tried to write a Lua script myself, but failed, because I do not understand well how pandoc works.

For example, I have tried returning a `Para` with the contents of the previous one + a page break from the `Header` function like this:

```lua
function Header(el)
    if el.level == 1 then
        local t = { pandoc.RawBlock('openxml', '<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>'), el }
        return pandoc.Para(t)
    end
    return el
end
```

However, it just ends up wiping all of the headers.
I have tried a few other alterations of the same idea, neither of which worked.

The trouble in Lua is mainly the fact that there is no static analysis and no Intellisense. I may be doing something completely inadequate in this code without any compiler errors and without even realising it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following should fix that:

```lua
local pagebreak = '<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>'
function Header(el)
    if el.level == 1 then
        -- return both the page break and the header as a list
        return { pandoc.RawBlock('openxml', pagebreak), el }
    end
    -- No `return el` needed, as not returning any value is the same as
    -- returning the original value.
end
```

The error reporting of pandoc during unmarshalling, i.e., while retrieving objects from Lua, is not great, to say the least. Ideally, pandoc should report the type error that comes from wrapping a list of "blocks" in a `Para`, as that constructor should only accept "inlines".

In case you are curious: I'm working on fixing this by switching to a different marshalling strategy, see [this PR](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/7191). It's taking a while, but we'll get there.

Comment: tarleb, first off, thank you for your work on pandoc and especially the section-bibliographies.lua filter. I am looking for a way to automatically have page breaks inserted after the references sections (i.e., before the following sections, which are usually marked by headers). I tried to edit the section-bibliographies.lua and insert the code above, but it didn't do anything (I was expecting it to insert a page break). What am I missing (besides a lot, since I know next to nothing about lua filters).

Comment: @streamline that's an interesting question but not easy to answer in a comment. Maybe you could post a separate question for this? I don't have much time for pandoc right now, but I'll try to take a look.

Comment: Tarleb, thank you for answering.  I have posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77001727/2836366 . Any insight you might give, when you have the time, it would be greatly appreciated!