# How to modify the section-bibliographies.lua Lua filter to generate page breaks after each bibliography sections?

Tags: lua, r-markdown, pandoc

The [section-bibliography.lua](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies) filter automatically creates distinct bibliography sections (references lists) at the end of each section (if a section is under heading 1, the bibliography section is generated as a section with heading 2, at the end of the heading 1 it is supposed to serve).

However, the consequent sections follow immediately after the end of the previous section’s bibliography section.

I want to add a page break after each bibliography section by modifying the [section-bibliography.lua](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies) filter, i.e., have the same lua filter (e.g., section-bibliographies.lua) output a page break after the bibliography sections it creates.

I would like the solution to work for Word documents, but I take what I can get (odt, pdf, etc.).

I am aware of other ways of obtaining this result, i.e., by modifying the word template, or by generating separate documents, or by using the [multibib.lua](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/multibib) filter, or, of course, by manually inserting page breaks “after” compiling everything, but I would like the filter itself to output the page break (and understand how it is done).

Note, the closest solution to what I want is given by the multibib.lua filter, but the problem is that if you have many sections with a lot of citations within each section, it quickly becomes too cumbersome to generate separate bib files for each section. I rather have a single bib file, which section-bibliographies.lua does an excellent job gathering and parsing all citation for each section and outputting different bibliography sections but it does not do that page break after each bibliography section.

I tried to do some modifications based on [this answer to a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155705/2836366) and on the [pagebreak](https://github.com/tarleb/lua-filters/tree/ee0910e595f6c7a77902cbc8463f34fad6b3bf15/pagebreak) filter, but the lua filter I modified does nothing different than before.

Many thanks to [Tarleb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2425163/tarleb) for [his work on Pandoc](https://github.com/tarleb)!